# Azure Functions pricing based on usage or tier

Tags: azure-functions

This seems like a dumb question but I'll ask anyway for posterity if nothing else. I read this in the [Functions Pricing page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/functions/):

> Azure Functions execution time is metered in Gigabyte Seconds(GB-s) which are calculated by multiplying the memory size in Gigabytes of your app by the sum of execution time in seconds [...] Expected memory size for a function app must be preselected in 128MB increments between 128MB and 1,536MB. The larger the memory tier, the more GB-s are consumed per second.

This makes me think that pricing is based on tier "chunks" combined with execution time. For example, a 128 MB Function would cost less than a 512 MB Function if they both ran for five seconds, regardless of what they do. However, the [Functions site itself](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-scale/) mentions the working set of the application. That context isn't specifically around pricing, though.

My question is: is Functions pricing based purely *selected memory tier*, or is it based on *actual memory usage* (both over time)? If you select 1536 MB as your tier but you only ever use 100 MB, are you essentially wasting time?

Answer (score 1):

This works, today, based on what you selected for memory tier. The process which is executing your Functions is limited to this memory amount.

There are other benefits which aren't promised, but can be observed, when increased. This can help reduce "noisy neighbors" on the VM you're running on, which gives more CPU and network throughput.

Generally, I'd recommend selecting the closest size to what you think you need and then doing some e2e perf testing where you play with the slider. It may or may not help you, and it may or may not be worth it to you to pay extra for the improvement you realize.

Comment: Is this still the case? I don't remember selecting a memory tier at any point when setting up functions (I'm still very new to them though!)

Comment: Yeah, this was true in preview, but it was removed once v1 GAs